# How To Position Child DIV While Using Bootstrap Responsive Site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I am new to Bootstrap, responsive web design, and am trying to create a page for my band but I am running into a few issues. I will try to explain as best as I can my situation and I greatly appreciate any and all help...

I have a div that has a background image of the band and I need it centered in the screen (regardless of the size of the screen) inside of one of Bootstrap's container DIV's. On top of that image, I have another image that I want to include. I am able to get that result so far. The problem I am running into is when I try to position the child DIV inside of the parent DIV. I have tried to set the parent DIV with a **position: relative** and the child DIV with a **position: absolute**, but as I begin to resize the screen, the inside image suddenly enlargens and stretches outside of the parent DIV. Also, when using this method and trying to position the child DIV 75% from the top of the parent DIV by using **top: 75%;**, it makes the image jump out of the parent again and puts it down at the bottom of the screen.

Here is the code that I have used so far but cannot get to work. Again, any help at all would be greatly appreciated as I am new to Bootstrap and responsive design but I would love to figure this stuff out. Thanks in advance!

**MY HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bandphoto">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 theband-title">
            <img src="images/theband.png" class="img-responsive ">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MY CSS:**

```
.bandphoto {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 2000px;
    min-height: 999px;
    background: url(images/bandphoto.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.theband-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w3mgQ

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, please advise with and feel free to educate me as well so that I can better understand this stuff.

Comment: Fiddle added above. See if you can replicate the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to avoid using absolute positioning (because it's very difficult to keep centered), and don't try to force Bootstrap elements when they're not needed. It's not clear to me how you want to position the inner image because I have no size reference, but maybe this gets you closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w3mgQ/3/

```
.bandphoto {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 2000px;
    min-height: 999px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/600x600/333333);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.theband-title {
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bandphoto">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" class="theband-title img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are getting closer....we have centered the inner img class="theband-title" inside of the DIV. What I need to do now is vertically position that image down...maybe 75%...from the top of the parent DIV. The band-title image is only 146px tall, so there should be plenty of room to move it vertically inside of the DIV. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this inside of the responsive design?

Comment: I have tried setting padding-top: 75%, but that makes the image pop outside of the DIV which I cannot have. I have tried using top: 75%; and that has no effect on the site whatsoever. I have even tried vertical-align: middle, but that too has no effect. I'm completely out of ideas on my end. LOL

Comment: Here is the fiddle I tried but still with no luck. But at least you might be able to see some of the sizes of the div's and images that I am working with. http://jsfiddle.net/DanAdams/QN5qv/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `display:table` and his friends. Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating:
http://jsfiddle.net/VcFf9/4/

I've set the container to be 100% height, and then vertically aligned the background and the content of the cell. Bootstrap's grid lends itself quite well to display:table, so try it out! :D